# Embedding Bokeh graphs while maintaining linked axis

Tags: python, flask, graph, embed, bokeh

I have linked the x axis of my bokeh graphs together by simply sharing the same x_range:

graph2.x_range = graph1.x_range

When I zoom-in/out or change the x-axis of one graph in any way, the other graph adjust with it. I really like this functionality.
However, when I embed the bokeh graphs in an html template they are not connected anymore.

script, div = components(graphs).
The components function returns a script that contains the data for your plot and provides a target div to display the plot view.

I added script and div in the placeholders of my html template, which is then loaded with Flask.

Everything works fine, but the graphs are not connected anymore.
It looks like the graps are embedded separately and therefore they cannot be linked together. I wonder if there is a method to do this.

If anyone has had this issue before, pls help :)
I used this documentation:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.1/docs/user_guide/embed.html

Comment: Please check the example [`embed_multiple`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.0/examples/embed/embed_multiple.py). It looks like this example explains your usecase. If I am right the important lines are `39-41`.

Comment: THANK YOU, it does work. I actually tried this before, but I must have made a mistake with the script and div placeholders. To clarify for others: When embedding graphs together like this (via a dictionary) you end up with 1 html script and 2 div's instead of 2 scripts and 2 div's. Apparently the 1 html file is necessary for linked axis to work.

Comment: Linked interactions can only apply to objects that are in the same Bokeh *Document*. That is why `components` can accept multiple objects in a single call, and return one script and mulitple divs. The one script contains the full *Document*. If you make separate calls to `components` then you are creating separate *Documents* and the objects in each cannot be linked.